# Which old abilities changed their effect in Pokemon Sun Moon?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, pokemon-seventh-generation

I've heard that some old abilities changed their effect in Pokemon Sun&Moon, some of them being nerfed and other buffed.

For example:

- **[Gale Wings](https://www.gamnesia.com/news/talonflames-gale-wings-ability-has-been-severely-nerfed-in-pokemon-sun-moon)** now only gives Flying attacks priority when the Pokemon it's at full health.
- **[Prankster](https://twitter.com/pokemon_PhD/status/799099789476499456)** moves now don't affect enemy Dark-type Pokemon.

Is there a list of these changes? Or at least more examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full list of updated abilities can be found [here](http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/updatedabilities.shtml). In addition to the two you have listed, there are three others. These abilities are:

[**Parental Bond**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/parentalbond.shtml)

- Updated:

  > Every move used by the Pokémon will hit twice. The damage inflicted by the second hit is reduced to 25%.
- Difference:

  > Second hit only does 25% of the first hit's damage rather than 50%.

[**Weak Armor**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/weakarmor.shtml)

- Updated:

  > Physical attacks to the Pokémon lower its Defense stat but sharply raise its Speed stat.
- Difference:

  > The Speed stat now increases by two stages rather than one

[**Pixilate**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/pixilate.shtml), [**Aerilate**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/aerilate.shtml), and [**Refrigerate**](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/refrigerate.shtml)

- > The power boost has been decreased from 30% to 20%

Comment: Thank you! But I think you confused the "description" column, that's actually the current effect :)

Comment: @pinckerman, oh you're right, let me update this